# Plotly chart exceeds Bootstrap grid when resizing Flask Web App

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, twitter-bootstrap, flask, plotly

I use bootstrap 3.3.7 for its grid and responsiveness in my web app (Flask App). It works pretty well with all the plotly subplots I created except for a single plot. When the browser is in full-page or if I resize a little bit, I don't have any problem :

[image]

However, if I resize too much the plot exceeds the section height and generates a white space.

[image]

I have tried to add a `margin-right`, a `padding-right`, to change the class of the div `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6` into `col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6` (the chart become very very small), to change the margin inside the javascript code that produces the plot...

And as you can see the subplots in the below the GREEKS title are well displayed whatever the resize applied...

Here is the html code for this section :

```
<section id="payoff" class="background-img">
<!-- Table code here -->
<div class="container-fluid" id="results">
    <div class="row" style="padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 30px;">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6" style="padding-top:40px;">
            <div class="plotly-graph-div" id="plot-payoff"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

Any help would be really appreciated! Thanks a lot

Comment: While I don't see your complete source it seems that you already had a look at https://plot.ly/javascript/responsive-fluid-layout/ from your second screenshot. Maybe you missed to calculate the width in `px` for your upper plot.

Comment: Thanks @bixel for your answer. As you noticed I already checked for making the charts responsive and it works pretty well. I do not set the width for any charts (neither the upper one nor all the subplots). I only set margins because it seems that the width is automatically set by Plotly, am I wrong ? Is there a css property that I missed for the div ?

Comment: If I am not mistaken, plotly uses the calculated width which might not get updated properly when you resize the screen. At least the width property is being set in above js snippet (via `d3.[...].style({width: [...]})`). So you just might need to add the relative width somewhere. Anyway its much simpler to help if you share everything of your relevant code. Maybe try to get a minimum working/breaking example.

Comment: The problem is solved, a col-offset-lg-1was troubling the grid when resizing.. I don't know why it reacted this way but as soon as I removed this offset things went better! Thanks for your help @bixel